# mxnet: CUDA Check failed: e == cudaSuccess (803 vs. 0) : system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination

Tags: gpu, docker-container, mxnet

As mxnet nvidia froums and github does not answer questions properly and also they don't have good community like stackoverflow I ask this question here.

**Host:**

```
Linux XYZ 5.15.0-76-generic #83~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 21 20:23:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Host Nvidia Driver Version:**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.108.03   Driver Version: 510.108.03   CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 26%   35C    P8     6W /  75W |    265MiB /  4096MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1063      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 92MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1338      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               26MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2078      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          144MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and cuda version is 11.6

```
USER@XYZ:~$ nvcc -V

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Feb_10_18:23:41_PST_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.112
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.30978841_0
```

**Problem:**

I installed **nvidia-container-toolkit** to run containers by enabling nvidia.
I have pulled `mxnet/python:1.9.1_gpu_cu112_py3` docker image. Then I want to [check if mxnet uses my gpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076092/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-mxnet-uses-my-gpu). So I run docker container

```
docker run -it --runtime=nvidia --gpus all mxnet/python:1.9.1_gpu_cu112_py3 /bin/bash
```

Then by checking nvidia driver version in container to be ensure that container runs with gpus:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.108.03   Driver Version: 510.108.03   CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 26%   34C    P8     6W /  75W |    278MiB /  4096MiB |      5%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Which shows cuda version is 11.2 . Now, in docker container I check **mxnet** by running these codes in `python3.7`:

```
import mxnet as mx
mx.context.num_gpus()
```

But, I have got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mxnet/context.py", line 275, in num_gpus
    check_call(_LIB.MXGetGPUCount(ctypes.byref(count)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 246, in check_call
    raise get_last_ffi_error()
mxnet.base.MXNetError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../include/mxnet/base.h", line 458
CUDA: Check failed: e == cudaSuccess (803 vs. 0) : system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination
```

So, mxnet could not identifying my GPUs.

**It seems that there is a problem with cuda version in host and container.**

By googling I found a solution to resolve this problem: [system has unsupported display driver / cuda driver combination](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1256). I remove all `libcuda.so` and it's symlink in container in the directory `/usr/local/cuda-11.2/compat/` and finally testing `mxnet` successfully:

```
Python 3.7.13 (default, Apr 24 2022, 01:04:09) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mxnet as mx
>>> mx.context.num_gpus()
1
```

**My question:**

By removing libcuda.so in container cuda version in container is 11.6 :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.108.03   Driver Version: 510.108.03   CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 26%   35C    P8     6W /  75W |    282MiB /  4096MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It seems that `nvidia-container-toolkit` binds `libcuda.so` from host. But, it makes a dependency between host and my container and it is not desired.

1. How could I remove this dependency?
2. Is there any way to edit configuration file of `nvidia-container-toolkit` to not bind `libcuda.so` with host?
3. Is this problem specific to `mxnet` framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to remove that dependency? For what it's worth, binding the host's `libcuda.so` into the container (along with all the other components of NVidia's drivers) is *highly desireable*, since the drivers must match exactly the version of the kernel module running on the *host*. If I were in your position, I'd move heaven and hell to get rid of any GPU related libraries and shared objects inside the container, for exactly the driver mismatch problems you experienced.

Comment: @datenwolf, I tested multi docker images with other frameworks like `Tensorflow` or `Pytorch` and for none of them I didn't have a such problem. I'm expecting to do not deleting any files in container. Removing GPU related libraries and shared objects inside the container is another challenge and I tried to edit binding files of `nvidia-container-toolkit` like in `/etc/cdi/nvidia.yaml`  but I don't get any success.

Comment: Looks like you didn't downgrade CUDA correctly.
Check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5eJTzhGe2QE

Comment: @SickerDude43 , why should I downgrade CUDA? If I have a RTX 4090 and I want to run docker container with cuda 10.1 , how could I install cuda 10.1 on RTX 4090? Why should I ignore those capability of the newest cuda version and downgrade cuda on host?

Comment: @gunnergunner Sorry misread the question. The first error was caused by the wrong CUDA version. The development came to a halt in the end of last year. So I don't expect them to release any support for them soon. Another workaround would be to either downgrade CUDA or switch to another framework

Comment: @SickerDude43, I have tested multiple docker container and we do not have such challenge for Pytorch, Tensorflow frameworks.

Comment: @gunnergunner Honestly I'm not getting what you want to do. Like datenwolf said I also don't understand why you want to remove the "dependency" that host and container have the same driver versions? Also you already solved the problem and since I assume MXNet runs on the host with the host's hardware, why shouldn't it bind the host's libcuda as well?